# Firebase Java client authentication

Tags: java, api, authentication, client, firebase

Trying to create standalone Java application but can't authenticate.

```
import com.firebase.client.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/");   
    ref.authAnonymously(new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError arg0) {               
        System.out.println("Not Authenticated: " + arg0);               
      }

      @Override
      public void onAuthenticated(AuthData arg0) {
        System.out.println("Authenticated.");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Always begets the following authentication error:

```
    Not Authenticated: FirebaseError: There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: Connection refused: connect
```

Note:

1. Same result using authWithPassword()
2. URL can be pinged from command line
3. Anonymous authentication IS turned on at the authentication host site
4. Anonymous authentication WORKS from web app
5. Using firebase-client-jvm-2.0.0.jar

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are we authenticating from an android device or vanilla Java? Has this error persisted over time or was it temporary?

Comment: What environment are you running in and do normal sets/addValueEventListener work?

Comment: Is there a proxy in your env? I think you should review it if there is....